# How to add dynamic subdomain on flutter web

Tags: flutter, subdomain, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I use [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular) plugin. This is my website https://shophub.store/ if I use a URL like this https://shophub.store/fr It's working fine. But I need a subdomain like this https://fr.shophub.store/. Does anybody know about this answer this question

Comment: subdomains are a completely different domain handled by your domain provider. It's not something you can achieve with Flutter.

Comment: Not actual subdomain bro, add a prefix to URL, like this javascript function

""" function changeLanguage(language) {
    var url = window.location.href
    var newUrl = url.replace(/^http:\/\//, 'http://' + language + '.')
    windows.location = newUrl;
} """

Comment: You cant do this in dart and even if you could you cant use https://fr.shophub.store/.... as long as you dont own the domain fr